# Download MP3 File using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, mp3

I'm running a Django server with some MP3 files on it, and it's set up so I can send a JSON request with the "songId" of the file I want and it returns the specified MP3.

This works when I try it on Postman but I can't figure out how to receive it with Volley on Android. Any time I try to change the response object from JSON, I get errors. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: This is the code that I normally use to get JSON responses

```
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject().put("songId", "43");

            JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,
                    url,
                    jsonObject,
                    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("REST Response", response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("REST Error", error.toString());
                        }
                    })
            {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("StoredValues", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "null");
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Token " + token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
                @Override
                public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                    return 10000;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                    return 10000;
                }

                @Override
                public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
                    Log.e("Volley error", error.toString());
                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Response", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code that you have done for this?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman sure

Comment: are you getting json response from server or mp3 file?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman from the server. However, it's returning an MP3 file in my case now and I don't know how to get that instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have can use this custom request class for downloading your file

```
  class InputStreamVolleyRequest extends Request<byte[]> {
    private final Response.Listener<byte[]> mListener;
   private Map<String, String> mParams;

    //create a static map for directly accessing headers
   public Map<String, String> responseHeaders ;

    public InputStreamVolleyRequest(int method, String mUrl ,Response.Listener<byte[]> listener,
                                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener, HashMap<String, String> params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(method, mUrl, errorListener);
         // this request would never use cache.
         setShouldCache(false);
         mListener = listener;
         mParams=params;
   }

   @Override
   protected Map<String, String> getParams()
         throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
      return mParams;
   };
 @Override 
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();                
  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return params; 
} 

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(byte[] response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<byte[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        //Initialise local responseHeaders map with response headers received
        responseHeaders = response.headers;

        //Pass the response data here
        return Response.success( response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```

And can make your request like that

```
   String mUrl= <YOUR_URL>;
   HashMap<String,String>hasMap = new HashMap<>();
   hashMap.put("songId","1");
InputStreamVolleyRequest request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, mUrl,
        new Response.Listener<byte[]>() { 
             @Override 
             public void onResponse(byte[] response) { 
           // TODO handle the response 
            try { 
            if (response!=null) {

              FileOutputStream outputStream;
              String name=<FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION e.g reference.txt>;
                outputStream = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(response);
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Download complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
} ,new Response.ErrorListener() {

  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO handle the error
    error.printStackTrace();
  }
}, hashmap);
          RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack());
          mRequestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: How can I add a custom header to that?

Comment: Just override getHeaders() method in InputStreamVolleyRequest class

Comment: @EthanShoe you need to send your values using parameters you can't get a file from server using JsonRequest.. You have to send your songid in parameter